# Python - how to shorten operations

Tags: python

I know in Java if you want to add one to a variable you can use x++ is there anything similar to this in Python.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
x += 1
```

Increment operator does not exist in python.

As Lattyware pointed out, there is not as much need for an increment operator as in e.g. Java or C. If you have a loop that relies on `i+=1` in python, you maybe want to rethink your code.

Just as an example:

Avoid:

```
idx = 0
for e in L:
    print (idx, e)
    idx += 1

for idx in range (len (L) ): print (idx, L [idx] )
```

Try:

```
for idx, e in enumerate (L): print (idx, e)
```

Also, when the sequences you need are beyond the scope of pure integer ranges (e.g. yielding strings or objects or anything), you should think about generators:

```
def weirdSequence (v):
    while True:
        yield v
        if v == 1: break
        v = v * 3 + 1 if v % 2 else v // 2

for i in weirdSequence (7): print (i)
```

Comment: +1, Beat me to it. I'll note that this makes a lot of sense in Python. Adding one to a value is a much less common operation (due to the lack of indexing things, the way loops work, etc...), and hence it doesn't make sense to special case it, for two characters difference. It also means it's easier to change that plus one to something else (which is more likely in cases outside of those common in other languages).

Comment: Good point Lattyware. As there is no omnipresent `i++` in python, the need for an increment operator is almost non existant.

Comment: Also note that in python, `int` types are **immutable**.  It's a little unclear what `i++` would actually do since it can't change `i` ...

Answer (score 0):

As Hyperboreus says, no `x++` operator in Python. I think it's interesting to guess at why - I think it's that Python makes a point of assignment *not* being an expression, and users of `x++` experienced in other languages might expect the result of this expression to be the un-incremented value of x. If assignment isn't an expression with a value, then there is not difference between `x++` and `++x`. I think having one of these but not the other would be confusing, but having them both do the same thing would be redundant.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear -- In C and other languages `i++` mutates the value of `i` -- but in python, `int` types are *immutable*, so you **can't** mutates the value of `i`.

Comment: Well, in C `i = i + 1` or `i = 3` also means mutate, but Python does keep that. But I see your point, something about `=` in Python makes me think of names in a way that `++` doesn't.

Comment: in python, when you do `i = i + 1`, you create a **new** object.  The `i` after the assignment isn't the same (think memory address) as the `i` before the assignment.  The difference may seem academic, but it really isn't.  This makes a **HUGE** difference.  (consider doing this inside a function where `i` is an input)

Comment: Agreed, but Python shares this notation with C, where `=` does mean mutate. So I argue it's not sufficient to say that the reason Python doesn't take `++` from C is that it mutates the value, because in C `=` mutates much as `++` does.

Comment: No, in python, `=` does **not mean mutate**, that's the point that I'm trying to make here ... `=` means "bind a name to an object".

Comment: Sorry, I'm being unclear - I'm saying in **C** it **does** mean mutate, so we're already changing the meaning of one operator, so why not of another.